# Are the pronunciations of "real" and "reel" same?

Tags: pronunciation

[image]

[image]

Why do the British Sound Symbols are the same, but the Americans' are different?

Comment: In my (British) lect they sound the same (though I would transcribe them as ['riəl], not [ri:l]). I wasn't aware that they were different in AmE, but I don't know. Evidently the compilers of your dictionary think so.

Comment: When it comes to pronunciation, there is no single AmE - there are many dialects. I'm from the northeast and pronounce these words the same, but I can imagine people from the southeast pronouncing **reel** with a pure vowel, but **real** with a diphthong or even two syllables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with accent differences, it might not even be universal throughout the United States. I'm from the Southern United States and I have heard people pronounce real all sorts of ways. If you pronounce them the same people will understand from context or might not even notice your technically pronouncing it differently.

Answer (score 2):

I am British, and I speak (mostly) Received Pronunciation, and I pronounce real, zeal, meal, etc with a dipthong, and reel, feel, keel, heel, etc without.